# simple jQuery dynamic pagination

Tags: jquery

rather than downloading and using someone else's awesome plugin, I wanted to write my own pagination script.

here's what I have so far

My question is how would I do the sort function more efficiently? is there a way to identify based off of the var first that I declared and its id relative to the rows and determine something like #something5 is the fifth row, so iterate from the 6th row to the 11th row? instead of using the .next() functions as shown.

```
 <div id="rows">
     <div class="row" id="something1">something1</div>
     <div class="row" id="something2">something2</div>
     <div class="row" id="something3">something3</div>
     <div class="row" id="something4">something4</div>
     <div class="row" id="something5">something5</div>
     <div class="row" id="something6">something6</div>
     <div class="row" id="something7">something7</div>
     <div class="row" id="something8">something8</div>
     <div class="row" id="something9">something9</div>    
     <div class="row" id="something10">something10</div>
     <div class="row" id="something11">something11</div>
     <div class="row" id="something12">something12</div>
 </div>
 <a href="#" id="prev">prev</a>
 <a href="#" id="next">next</a>
 <br />
 <span id="total"></span>

 var max = 5;

 function sort(x) {
      if (x == "prev") {
           var first = $('#rows .row:visible').first().attr('id');
           if (first != "something5") {
                $('#rows .row').hide();
                $('#'+first).prev('div').show();
                $('#'+first).prev('div').prev('div').show();
                $('#'+first).prev('div').prev('div').prev('div').show();
                $('#'+first).prev('div').prev('div').prev('div').prev('div').show();
                $('#'+first).prev('div').prev('div').prev('div').prev('div').prev('div').show();
           }
      } else {
          var last = $('#rows .row:visible').last().attr('id');
          $('#rows .row').hide();
          $('#'+last).next('div').show();
          $('#'+last).next('div').next('div').show();
          $('#'+last).next('div').next('div').next('div').show();
          $('#'+last).next('div').next('div').next('div').next('div').show();
          $('#'+last).next('div').next('div').next('div').next('div').next('div').show();
      }
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
      var total = $('#rows .row').size();
      var pages = total / max;
      $("#total").text("page " + pages + " of " + total);

      $('#rows .row').hide();   

      for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
          $('#rows .row').eq(i).css('display', 'block');
      }

      $('#prev').click(function() {
          sort("prev");
      });

      $('#next').click(function() {
          sort("next");
      });   
 });
```

Jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/DcNLJ/

Comment: This is not  sort functionality. but pagination functionality. your sort function doesn't yield any values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

http://jsfiddle.net/DcNLJ/1/

What left fot u to do  is to take care of edge scenario (prevent to prev at start or next at end)

```
var max = 5;
var pageNum = 0;
var _ = $('#rows .row');

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    var total = _.length;
    var pages = total / max;


    $('#prev').click(function ()
    {
        pageNum--;
        sort("prev");
    });

    $('#next').click(function ()
    {
        pageNum++;
        sort("next");
    });

    $('#next').trigger('click');

});


function sort(a)
{
    _.hide();
    _.filter(function (i)
    {
        return i >= (pageNum - 1) * max && i < (pageNum) * max;
    }).show();
    $("#total").text("page " + pageNum + " of " + Math.ceil($('#rows .row').length / max));
}
```

Comment: thanks, not familiar with the filter function, can you explain the i>=(pageNum-1)*max  && i<  (pageNum)*max code, please? goes through each .row div, checks if its integer value (?) is larger or greater than pageNum - 1 * max and also if it is less than pageNum * max and then returns true / false and does a .show() on the truth ones?

Comment: Did you try to put value in this formula ? I think it's pretty straight forward.